# Naviagtion XYZ cant be found from current destination()

Tags: android, kotlin, navgraph, navigation-compose, navigation-android

I often get this error a lot in all my projects

```
Navigation action/destination com.speakerbooster.volumebass.equalizersound.amplifier:id/action_premiumFragment_to_dashboardFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.speakerbooster.volumebass.equalizersound.amplifier:id/autoCleanerFragment) label=fragment_auto_cleaner class=com.iobits.tech.volumebooster.presentation.fragments.AutoCleanerFragment
```

Thats how i using navigations to navigate

```
if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.currentFragment) {
                   navigateTo(someactionId)
```

}

> and here is the navigateTo() function

```
fun Fragment.navigateTo(actionId: Int, destinationName: Int) {
    findNavController().navigate(
        actionId,
        null,
        NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(destinationName, true).build()
    )
}
```

Comment: The error message says the current destination is `R.id.autoCleanerFragment`. It sounds like you are missing that if check then, since there's no way the `currentDestination?.id` can change between the if check and the `navigate` call. Can you include the full stack trace and exactly where in your code the stack trace is coming from?

Comment: similar error stackTrace:@ianhanniballake
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.speakerbooster.volumebass.equalizersound.amplifier:id/action_autoCleanerFragment_to_premiumFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.speakerbooster.volumebass.equalizersound.amplifier:id/premiumFragment) label=fragment_premium class=com.iobits.tech.volumebooster.presentation.fragments.PremiumFragment
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1663)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavContro